# JavaFX8 MediaPlayer no sound error/wrong URL

Tags: java, javafx-8

I'm working on JavaFX 8 app and I'm trying to open MP3 file using MediaPlayer.
I had passed wrong URL errors and I've no exceptions right now, when I start such part of code, but app opens and there is no sound. Tried with some oracle tutorial and when i put such URL:  "http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/oow2010-2.flv" everything is working so I guess it's still wrong URL, but app is starting and I've litterally no clue whats wrong.

```
  public class Main extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
            //Add a scene
            Group root = new Group();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);

            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\SomeFile.mp3");
            Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toASCIIString());

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
            mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);

            // create mediaView and add media player to the viewer
            MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
            ((Group)scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(mediaView);
            //show the stage
            primaryStage.setTitle("Media Player");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the file is correctly located and loaded you can do the following:

```
file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()
```

If you are writing an app that plays various media files, consider using user interface to obtain paths to external file resources instead of hardcoding them. You can use [FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) or [DirectoryChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html)

Comment: sad result, app still starts and there is no sound

Comment: I have run the code with toASCIIString() and with toExternalForm(). Both times the mp3 file was played correctly. Hence, I can only assume that the SomeFile.mp3 is not located where it should be.

Comment: Well it seems like problem is somewhere deeper, coz I'm sure path is correct since if I write something wrong there is an instant exception that system cannot find file.

Comment: Can you try some other mp3/mp4 file?

Comment: weird thing but i've tried to use few others mp3 and those are working.

Comment: tried it right before u wrote, thats weird earlier ones werent working, thanks for help. I will just have to find out what is the problem with earlier ones

Comment: Glad it is now resolved. It seems the files which didn't work may have a weird mp3 encoding or something