# JavaFX MediaPlayer is not playing audio for some specific mp4 files

Tags: javafx, audio, video, media-player, mp4

I have a JavaFX application which uses a `MediaPlayer` and a `MediaView` to play videos. I've been testing with some `mp4` video's I have and it works perfectly fine, audio, visuals, all looks good. Only not for a specific type of `mp4` video.

I have the full series of a show I like on my hard drive, and for some reason when I try it with ANY of those videos, I can see the video play perfectly but the audio is just not there. The `MediaPlayer` is not muted, and the volume is at 1.0 (100%). When I use an `AudioSpectrumListener` it doesn't even fire, but it does with other videos.

I doubt the code matters since it works fine for any other video, but I'll put it anyways. I'm using an MVC design pattern, so the `MediaPlayer` is stored in a model object.

```java
public void openVideo() {
    File selectedFile = chooseFiles(VIDEO_EXTENSIONS); // opens file chooser for given extensions
    if (selectedFile == null) return;
    if (dataModel.getVideoPlayer() != null) dataModel.getVideoPlayer().dispose();
    dataModel.setVideoPlayer(new MediaPlayer(new Media(selectedFile.toURI().toString())));
    dataModel.getVideoPlayer().play();
}
```

The `MediaView` is bound to the `MediaPlayer` in the data model through this line of code:

```java
mediaView.mediaPlayerProperty().bindBidirectional(dataModel.videoPlayerProperty());
```

The videos that don't work are all about 22 minutes long and 1GB in size. I've attached a screenshot of the properties of a video that works fine, and one which doesn't play the audio.

[image: This one works fine] Works fine, this is a screen recording I made with OBS.

[image: This one won't play audio] Won't play audio, episode of a show I like to watch.

The only audio-difference is the bit rate, something I don't think should make any difference.

I am starting to think this may be a bug with javaFX, but I really hope that there's something I can do to make this work.

Comment: May your problem be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137986/javafx8-mediaplayer-no-sound-error-wrong-url)

Comment: @RushiSrinivas.K Changing the formatting of `file.toURI().toString()` to `file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()` or any variant of that doesn't make any difference. Like I said in the post, I can see that the video loads fine, it just doesn't detect the audio for some reason. I think one of the comments on that post might be right though, the files may be encoded slightly different from standard mp4 files. I might have to switch to a completely different MediaPlayer type if I want this to work, something like VLCJ. That would make it more complicated than I'd like though.